# Balanced or Well-balanced

Tags: word-choice, difference, adjectives, adverbs

What is the difference between the adjective "***balanced***" and "***well-balanced***".

For example,

> "*Many families do not realize the importance of a well-balanced diet.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Well balanced' doesn't really have any greater meaning other than the fact that adding 'well' as an adverb to any suitable verb suggests it has been done *in a good manner*, or *done properly*. Cambridge dictionary defines 'well-balanced' as *nicely or evenly balanced, arranged, or regulated*.

It could be argued that 'well-balanced' doesn't really mean any more than just 'balanced'. Something is either balanced (in a state of balance), or it is not. If you think about the most literal use of 'balance' - a pair of scales must have precisely the same weight on either side to be balanced. Balance is an absolute, there are no gradations. Further, the associated phrase '*carefully balanced*' could also be ambiguous as it could describe something that has been balanced in such a way that makes it more stable, or something so precisely balanced that it could easily be knocked off balance.

I suspect that 'well-balanced diet' is just an excuse to bring the word 'well' (which can also refer to *wellness*, ie physical health) alongside the word 'diet' to suggest that you can eat yourself to good health. 'Eating well' also means making good choices and eating a balanced variety of foods, so it could be a bringing together of these two phrases.